# Find substring between two indices in C++

Tags: c++, string

I want to find the substring between two indices. The [substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)(start_index, number_of_characters) function in C++ returns substring based on number of characters. Hence a small hack to use it with start and end indices is as follows:

```
 // extract 'go' from 'iamgoodhere'
 string s = "iamgoodhere";
 int start = 3, end = 4;
 cout<<s.substr(start,end-start+1); // go
```

What other methods exist in C++ to get the substring between two indices?

Comment: Why is `substr` insufficient for your purposes?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I was asked in an interview to not use `substr`, hence the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this:

```
std::string(&s[start], &s[end+1])
```

or this:

```
std::string(s.c_str() + start, s.c_str() + end + 1)
```

or this:

```
std::string(s.begin() + start, s.begin() + end + 1)
```

These approaches require that `end` is less than `s.size()`, whereas `substr()` does not require that.

Don't complain about the `+1`--ranges in C++ are always specified as inclusive begin and exclusive end.

Comment: Note that this is somewhat less safe than `substr` because `end >= s.size()` will result in UB.

Comment: @Wintermute: Yes, I was adding a note about that just now.

Comment: +1, then. I'd probably use iterators over `c_str()`, but that really doesn't matter. Actually, I'd probably use `substr` over any of these, but it answers the question. :P

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [John Zwinck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50548084/7706917) you can use [substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) in combination with [std::distance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance):

```cpp
auto size = std::distance(itStart, itEnd);
std::string newStr = myStr.subStr(itStart, size);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution,

```
std::string distance_finder(std::string str, int start, int end)
{
return str.substr(start, end - start);
}
```

Though, end always has to be grater than start.